# About rails expire_page routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

In my Rails4 app I use `actionpack-page_caching`.

I have a controller like this:

```
class CodeController < ApplicationController
    def home
    end
end
```

and the route:

```
 get "/code/:order/(:page)" => "code#home"
```

Then when I clear the page caching

```
 expire_page(:controller => 'code', :action => 'home')
```

I got the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"home", :controller=>"code"}
```

Why? and what should I do?

Comment: This method may be deprecated http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Caching/Pages/expire_page

Comment: actually what I mean is how to transform `get "/code/:order/(:page)" => "code#home"` to the format `(:controller => 'code', :action => 'home')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Rails guides

Page Caching has been removed from Rails 4. See the [actionpack-page_caching gem](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-page_caching). See [DHH's key-based cache expiration overview](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3113-how-key-based-cache-expiration-works) for the newly-preferred method.